# How to keep last route when user redirected to login -by Ngrx Effect angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, effect

Suppose user goes to http://sample.com/dashboard then login guard checks and he didn't login and redirected him to Login page. I want to get his last route(in this example http://sample.com/dashboard) and when he logged in redirect him to the route.
I just did it with Ngrx Effect, but...

```
    @Effect()
  getUserLoginData$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(userActions.GET_USER_DATA),
    switchMap(() => {
    return this.sessionService.getLoggedInUserInfo().pipe(
        map((success) => new userActions.GetUserDataSuccessAction(success)),
        catchError((error) => of(new uerActions.GetUserDataFailAction(error)))
      );
    })
  );

  @Effect({dispatch: false})
  public userLoginDataSuccess$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(userActions.GET_USER_DATA_SUCCESS),
    map((action: userActions.GetUserDataSuccessAction) => action),
    tap((data) => {
      if (data.url.includes('login'))
        this.router.navigate([RouteMap.DASHBOARD])
      else
        this.router.navigate([data.url])
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create for example a service that will keep track of your route history.

```
previousUrl: string;
constructor(router: Router) {
  router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log('prev:', this.previousUrl);
    this.previousUrl = e.url;
  });
}
```

And you can integrate it with the state management of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found its answer:

1- Add routerReducer to your state interface:

```js
    export interface State {
         ...
         routerReducer: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>;
    }
```

2- Init routerReducer in reducers object:

```js
    export interface State {
      ...
      routerReducer: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>;
    }
```

3- Create RouterSatetUrl interface:

```js
    export interface RouterStateUrl {
      url: string;
      params: Params;
      queryParams: Params;
    }
```

4- Create CustomSerializer:

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class CustomSerializer implements fromRouter.RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateUrl> {
      serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl {
        const {url} = routerState;
        const {queryParams} = routerState.root;
    
        let state: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = routerState.root;
        while (state.firstChild) {
          state = state.firstChild;
        }
        const {params} = state;
    
        return {url, params, queryParams};
      }
    }
```

5- Create a FeatureSelector to get current route whenever you want:

```js
    export const getRouterState = createFeatureSelector<fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>>('routerReducer');
```

6- And last step is use **getRouterState** where you want to get route info. For example i use it in one of my Effects:

```js
    @Effect({dispatch: false})
      public userLoginDataSuccess$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(userActions.GET_USER_DATA_SUCCESS),
        map((action: userActions.GetUserDataSuccessAction) => action),
        tap(() => {
          let getRouterState$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getRouterState).subscribe((data) => {
            if (!data.state || data.state.url.includes('login') || data.state.url == '/' || data.state.url == '') {
              this.router.navigate([RouteMap.DASHBOARD])
            } else {
              this.router.navigate([data.state.url])
            }
          });
    
          getRouterState$.unsubscribe();
        })
      );
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with history.back()

Regards!